# In AWK, is it possible to specify a range for operation?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Example: 
Given a comma separated file `"foo"` with `50` fields per line, I want to print `$0` if `$10 !=` the range from `1001` to `1010`.

I can do it using below code:

```
awk -F, '{if($10!=1001 && $10!=1002 && $10!=1003 && $10!=1004 && $10!=1005 && $10!=1006 && $10!=1007 && $10!=1008 && $10!=1009 && $10!=1010 ){print $0}}'
```

Yet this way is prone to errors.

Can it be done?

Comment: Do you also want to exclude 1001.23 or 1001.00 or 1.002e3 or 0x3F0?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, noting that I do not have such records.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
awk -F, '!( 1001 <= $10 && $10 <= 1010 )' file
```